# Pass multiple elements using forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to pass multiple elements from a component using `forwardRef`

I have this component and I want to pass separately `loader--holder` and `loader--holder__logo` to parent function component

```
const Loader = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="loader--holder" ref={ref1}>
      <div className="loader--holder__box">
        <div className="loader--holder__logo"ref={ref2}>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Parent component

```
export default function HomePage() {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  return (
   <div>
      <Loader ref={ref} />
   </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign to the forwarded ref what you need:

```
const Loader = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.current = {
        ref1,
        ref2,
      };
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div className="loader--holder" ref={ref1}>
      <div className="loader--holder__box">
        <div className="loader--holder__logo" ref={ref2}>
          <div>Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

// Usage
export default function HomePage() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in parent', ref);
  }, []);

  return <Loader ref={ref} />;
}
```

[image: Edit exciting-brook-xvwe1]